# checking similarity of last item in a list of list python

Tags: python, list

I have a long list of list, I want to check whether the last item of each list inside the big list if they are equal, if they are then I want to create a new list adding them in order and adding the item before  the item "^" into a new list of list, for example, I have the following format ( this is just an example, the data can be changed each time so the code should be generlized):

```
[[ " a", "b" , "^", "xxx"]
 [ " c", "d", "e" , "^", "xxx"]
 [ " a", "h" , "^", "nnn"]
 [ " c", "d", "s" , "^", "nnn"]]
```

I want to return:

```
list1 = [ "xxx", "nnn"]
```

corresponding in index to the created list of list:

```
list1= [ [b , e] , [ h, s] ]
```

taking the names right before the item of "^" and adding everything corresponding to the index in  list1, I don't know how to do the logic but my trial:

```
 def patterns(file_of_context):
      ### the original list of list
     list_of_context= context_file(file_of_context)
     for a in list_of_context:
         for b in a:
             if a[-1]==
```

Comment: Why is `'nnn'` in the result? There's only one of those in the input (there's `' nnn'` though).

Comment: Should `' xxx'` & `'xxx'` (and `' nnn'` & `'nnn'`) considered the same or not?

Comment: @niemmi , no   they should be diff

Comment: Could you then check your example data? All the 4 last items in the sublists are different.

Comment: for the last item in the first list ( the original), it's "xxx" thus we added the item right before "^", thus it's ["b"], when we found "xxx" again, we added "e" also to the sublist and visa versa @niemmi

Comment: The last item of first sublist is `' xxx'`, not `'xxx'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) where key is the last element from nested list and value is `list` containing the items before `'^'`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = [
    [" a", "b", "^", "xxx"],
    [" c", "d", "e", "^", "xxx"],
    [" a", "h", "^", "nnn"],
    [" c", "d", "s", "^", "nnn"]
]

res = OrderedDict()
for x in l:
    try:
        index = x.index('^')
        if index > 0:
            res.setdefault(x[-1], []).append(x[index - 1])
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(res.keys())
print(res.values())
```

Output:

```
['xxx', 'nnn']
[['b', 'e'], ['h', 's']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired output can be achieved with [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from `itertools` and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) from `functools`:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import groupby

list_of_lists = [[' a', 'b', '^', 'xxx'],
 [' c', 'd', 'e', '^', 'xxx'],
 [' a', 'h', '^', 'nnn'],
 [' c', 'd', 's', '^', 'nnn']]

final_list = []

for i in groupby(list_of_lists, key=lambda x: x[-1]):
  final_list.append(list(reduce(lambda x,y: (x[x.index("^")-1],y[y.index("^")-1]), i[1])))


print(list(set(map(lambda x: x[-1], list_of_lists))))

print(final_list)
```

I hope this helps.